# Mounted and working disk partition reports as "no filesystem", Spotlight won't index

Tags: macos, spotlight, filesystem

TL/DR: encrypted separate disk partition for /Users won't index

After installing too many junky apps, especially system monitors - I decided to reinstall.  I grabbed a USB external 1TB drive, backed up my main internal (815 GB used of 1 TB), and erased it.

I partitioned my internal drive and reinstalled macOS Sierra on the smaller main partition.  Then after googling for the best way to do it, I added the second partition as /Users to `/etc/fstab` using *vifs*. After some undesired juggling of accounts and locations - including putting an admin account elsewhere on the primary partition - my user account was working fine under /Users on the secondary partition.

Then I clicked on the disk in Finder and selected 'Encrypt.'

Well, not completely.  Spotlight simply won't touch the /Users partition.

Here is my `diskutil list` output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Beornholm               62.9 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS                         62.4 GB    disk0s4
   5:          Apple_CoreStorage                         873.8 GB   disk0s5
   6:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s6

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Beornholm              +62.5 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 B9E46FBB-B968-7BF4-4F97-13776548928A

                                 Unencrypted
```

diskutil info says it has no file system:

```
<snip>
   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Users
   File System:              None
</snip>
```

I'm not sure the encryption was successful. The Finder "Encrypt" option is still there.

Can someone help me figure out how I screwed this up?  I don't really want to start from scratch, unless you have an affordable option for fast data transfer on a 2011 MBP with USB 2.0.

Comment: I don't understand this nesting. Well, I understand it technically but what's the purpose of displacing the /Users folder on a small partition on the **same** disk (except an admin account somewhere else), mapping it back to the main system volume and then trying to encrypt everything?

Comment: I want to make it easier to do a fresh reinstall of the operating system on the main partition if needed without having to duplicate 850 MB of files from a backup.  I thought using a separate partition was a good way to isolate my user files.  Maybe this isn't the best way - I'm open to suggestions.